# NSFileManager copyItemAtPath toPath

Tags: objective-c, nsfilemanager

I wanna watch a folder, then copy `different extensioned & same filenamed` files to another directory/folder. But I check the files with

`if([myManager fileExistsAtPath:[(NSURL*)pathSource  path]]==YES`

it detects ,return YES, there is file in directory.But never copied any of Video-Audio-txt files with

`[myManager copyItemAtPath:@"/Users/.../CONTENTS/002BJ" toPath:@"/Users/.../CONTENTS/AUDIO/"; error:nil]`

codes. So what's my wrong or Is there any another way to copy/move files to directories?

Comment: Also I tried destinationPath with filename, but no action, no copy

Answer (score 1):

> When a file is being copied, the destination path must end in a
>   filename—there is no implicit adoption of the source filename.

```
NSString *path = @"/Users/.../CONTENTS/002BJ";
[myManager copyItemAtPath:path toPath:[@"/Users/.../CONTENTS/AUDIO/" stringByAppendingPathComponent:[path lastPathComponent] error:nil];
```

Comment: Thank you Parag, and now NSFileManager may not respond to '-copyItemAtPath:toPath:stringByAppendingPathCompanent::error' :((

Comment: NSError *error;
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:sourcePath toPath:[destinationPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[sourcePath lastPathComponent]] error:&error];

Comment: YESSS, Thanks so much. If you let me one more question. Do I have to type the extension? now this is the problem for me cause I have different files like a.xml and a.txt and a.BMP

Comment: [@"/Volumes/user/20.txt" lastPathComponent] will return 20.txt